# Doubleanimation Skew not working

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am trying to get this animation to work but for some reason nothing is happening when it is called by the Dispatch timer, any ideas?

```
    public static void Grass2(Canvas canvas, int boundry)
    {
        foreach (var element in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
        {
            var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
            if (elementName[0] == "grass")
            {
                var skewGrass = new DoubleAnimation
                    {
                        From = 0,
                        To = boundry,
                        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)),
                        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                        EasingFunction = new BackEase(),
                        AutoReverse = true
                    };
                element.BeginAnimation(SkewTransform.AngleXProperty, skewGrass);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to animate?

Comment: I am trying to skew a image (X axis) left and right to simulate it swaying in the wind.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to animate the `SkewTransform.AngleXProperty` on an object of type Image. That won't work since Image does not have this property. However, the Image's `RenderTransform` might be set to a SkewTransform, and that SkewTransform can be animated:

```
...
// each element's RenderTransform must be a SkewTransform
var transform = (SkewTransform)element.RenderTransform;
transform.BeginAnimation(SkewTransform.AngleXProperty, skewGrass);
```

Comment: Thanks for a serious answer and not all the rubbish that has since been removed :)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to stop all the animations and still doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to set each element's Rendertransform to a separate (new) SkewTransform instance, not all to the same?

Comment: There is only one grass element at the moment so it shouldn't be a problem at the moment as far as i am aware.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I tried. One element with an animated SkewTransform. Works fine for me. Perhaps you edit your question to provide more context.