# WPF transform a Border using the corners

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

I would like to know if there is a way to transform an element in WPF using the corners of the element. Or any other way I can achieve what I am trying to do.

I did a small image in photoshop to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a skew transform.Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673399/skew-animation-unable-to-animate for more information

Comment: I've tried using a SkewTransform, but it's not exactly what i need. With a SkewTransform the bottom right corner would be lower (Y axis), but what I want is the bottom right corner to be higher (Y axis). Unless I'm missing something

Comment: I found an article that does something similar but with Blend @ http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd80b9/creating-3d-plane-animated-video-in-expression-blend/

Comment: and heres another one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx